# How to convert sin_addr.S_un into char *?

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to get an IP address from a sender after he sent something to me. I'm using UDP socket, so the IP address of the sender will be automatically registered into `sin_addr` structure since I'm using `recvfrom()` function.

How do I manipulate the `sin_addr` structure and convert it into a `char *`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[inet_ntoa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

```
struct sockaddr_in in_sa; 
char* ip_addr_text = inet_ntoa( in_sa.sin_addr );
```

If you want to keep it for later use you should make a copy, for instance:

```
std::string ip_txt( inet_ntoa( in_sa.sin_addr ) );
// other stuff
std::cout << ip_txt << std::endl;
```

Comment: while your example is technically correct, it should be noted that if you don't use the `char*` produced immediately, you should make a copy of it into a buffer you own. `inet_ntoa` typically returns a pointer to an internal statically allocated array which will get overwritten during subsequent calls.

Comment: Also, inet_ntoa is not threadsafe, you may want to consider inet_ntop instead of your operating system supports it, which allows you to specify your own buffer instead of using an internal static one

Comment: I got this error: `Unhandled exception at 0x0016a8fa in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000168.`

Comment: Better post your code, you're likely passing a null pointer to inet_ntoa